# How to know the originator of a message in WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

I just want to know that is there any way to read the meta data of a file/message of whatsApp.
I just want to know that who is the originator of a particular message .
Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

The only way to confirm the originator is if he/she has been certified by WhatsApp. Business customers can undergo certification process, so that the messages delivered by them are marked with a special sign indicating that the sender is validated.